# Plotting figures side-by-side python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The following generates 2 plots, 1 on top of another on Jupyter notebook. How can make the function plotAllDist(...) take in plots from plot1Dist(...) and plot them as subplots, side-by-side instead?

I've tried reading some posts but to no avail...

```
def plot1Dist(x, sigmaJ, pmf, title):
    fig = plt.figure()

    freqTable = np.array(np.unique(sigmaJ, return_counts=True)).T
    simu = plt.plot(freqTable[:,0], freqTable[:,1], label='Simulation')
    dist = pmf * sum(freqTable[:,1])
    model = plt.plot(x, dist, label='Model')

    # add description to the plot
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    plt.xlabel('sigma')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 5))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()

def plotAllDist(x, sigmaJ, e, pmf0, pmf1, FLIPS):    
    ONES = [i for i in range(e.size) if e[i] == 1]
    ZEROS = [j for j in range(e.size) if e[j] == 0]

    if (FLIPS == 0):
        title = 'Distribution of sigma before bit-flipping'
    elif (FLIPS > 0):
        title = 'Distribution of sigma after ' + str(FLIPS) + ' flips'

    plot1Dist(x, sigmaJ[ZEROS], pmf0, title + ' (e=0)')
    plot1Dist(x, sigmaJ[ONES], pmf1, title + ' (e=1)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) and the [object-oriented API for matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_overview.html#the-object-oriented-api). First, avoid creating a new figure inside `plot1Dist`, since this will forcibly create a new plot every time (and thus, in a notebook, plot them one above the other in the screen).

I would amend your code like this:

```
def plot1Dist(ax, x, sigmaJ, pmf, title):
    "plots distribution onto Axes object `ax`."

    # Just replace all instances of `plt` with `ax`. Their APIs aren't exactly
    # the same but they are very similar
    freqTable = np.array(np.unique(sigmaJ, return_counts=True)).T
    simu = ax.plot(freqTable[:,0], freqTable[:,1], label='Simulation')
    dist = pmf * sum(freqTable[:,1])
    model = ax.plot(x, dist, label='Model')

    # add description to the plot
    ax.legend(loc="upper right")
    ax.set_xlabel('sigma')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    ax.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 5))
    ax.set_title(title)

def plotAllDist(x, sigmaJ, e, pmf0, pmf1, FLIPS):
    ONES = [i for i in range(e.size) if e[i] == 1]
    ZEROS = [j for j in range(e.size) if e[j] == 0]

    if (FLIPS == 0):
        title = 'Distribution of sigma before bit-flipping'
    elif (FLIPS > 0):
        title = 'Distribution of sigma after ' + str(FLIPS) + ' flips'

    # number of columns = 2, so that the plots are side by side
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 7))
    plot1Dist(axes[0], x, sigmaJ[ZEROS], pmf0, title + ' (e=0)')
    plot1Dist(axes[1], x, sigmaJ[ONES], pmf1, title + ' (e=1)')
```

I would really encourage you to check out the [object-oriented API](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_overview.html#the-object-oriented-api)! It is in my opinion much less confusing and more flexible than the "pyplot" API.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change ax.xlabel, ax.ylabel, ax.title, to ax.set_xlabel, ax.set_ylabel, ax.set_title and remove ax.show() for the code to run correctly though.

Comment: Ah, I didn't run the code myself, sorry. Glad it helped! I edited your changes into the code.